# nth child recipes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have some example HTML markup below, and what i'm looking to do it with is use an nth child recipe to show only (and specifically only) the 7th child when a media query is set to a specific screen size. Can this be done? Or am i better hiding all children of the images class, the targeting the 7th child with another nth child recipe?

```
<div class = "imageCollection">
<ul class="images">
    <li class="image"></li>
    <li class="image"></li>
    <li class="image"></li>
    <li class="image"></li>
    <li class="image"></li>
    <li class="image"></li>
    <li class="image"></li>
    <li class="image"></li>
    <li class="image"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `not()` combined with `nth-child`:

```css
.images li:not(:nth-child(7)) {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class = "imageCollection">
<ul class="images">
    <li class="image">1</li>
    <li class="image">2</li>
    <li class="image">3</li>
    <li class="image">4</li>
    <li class="image">5</li>
    <li class="image">6</li>
    <li class="image">7</li>
    <li class="image">8</li>
    <li class="image">9</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: See, personally I'd set `li` to `display:none` and then use `:nth-child(7)` to set that one back to `block`, but that's just me :D Either way works.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol but from what I understand, the OP is aware about the manner to have 2 CSS declaration, I think he was looking of a shortcut to be able to use only one selector

Answer (score 1):

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .image:nth-child(7) {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class = "imageCollection">
<ul class="images">
    <li class="image">1</li>
    <li class="image">2</li>
    <li class="image">3</li>
    <li class="image">4</li>
    <li class="image">5</li>
    <li class="image">6</li>
    <li class="image">7</li>
    <li class="image">8</li>
    <li class="image">9</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**this is if you want to hide all except child number** 7

```css
.image:not(:nth-child(7)) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class = "imageCollection">
<ul class="images">
    <li class="image">1</li>
    <li class="image">2</li>
    <li class="image">3</li>
    <li class="image">4</li>
    <li class="image">5</li>
    <li class="image">6</li>
    <li class="image">7</li>
    <li class="image">8</li>
    <li class="image">9</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The `n` is unneeded, and will in fact fail to work as intended if there are 14 items. Or 21.